# Creating a JTwain applet in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, applet

I'm doing a bit of testing with the JTwain Library. I need to attach scanning functionality to a Django App. I've got a bit of code that will run locally but I can't make it work in an applet.

I'm back, trying to get the demo applet to run. I've created an eclipse 'runable jar' (I've had to add a dummy Main to one of the classes). And I'm getting the following output from the plugin console when I load the page in a browser -

```
    java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (java.lang.RuntimePermission loadLibrary.AspriseJTwain)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkLink(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at com.asprise.util.jtwain.SourceManager.init(SourceManager.java:222)
    at com.asprise.util.jtwain.SourceManager.<init>(SourceManager.java:36)
    at com.asprise.util.jtwain.SourceManager.instance(SourceManager.java:28)
    at JTwainApplet.scan(JTwainApplet.java:39)
    at JTwainApplet.init(JTwainApplet.java:69)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.asprise.util.jtwain.lowlevel.Control.performAction(ILjava/lang/Object;)Z
    at com.asprise.util.jtwain.lowlevel.Control.performAction(Native Method)
    at com.asprise.util.jtwain.lowlevel.Control.unloadSourceManager(Control.java:93)
    at com.asprise.util.jtwain.SourceManager.closeSourceManager(SourceManager.java:120)
    at JTwainApplet.scan(JTwainApplet.java:57)
    at JTwainApplet.init(JTwainApplet.java:69)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Scan
```

Below is the structure of the Jar I've created.

```
C:\PythonProjects\CacheProject\media\java>jar tf demo.jar
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
JTwainApplet.class
ImageDisplayer$1.class
ImageDisplayer.class
META-INF/
META-INF/ASPRISE.DSA
com/
com/asprise/
com/asprise/util/
com/asprise/util/jtwain/
com/asprise/util/jtwain/ImageGenerator.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/InvalidStateException.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/JTwainConstants.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/JTwainException.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/OperationException.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/Source.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/SourceManager.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/Capability.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/Control.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/DataType.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/DataTypeIdentity.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/DataTypeImageInfo.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/DataTypeImageLayout.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/DataTypeVersion.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ItemType.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ItemTypeFix32.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ItemTypeFrame.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ItemTypeInteger.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ItemTypeString.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/OperationResult.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ValueContainer.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ValueContainerArray.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ValueContainerEnumeration.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ValueContainerOneValue.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/lowlevel/ValueContainerRange.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/FileUploader.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/ImageDisplayPanel.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/UploadApplet.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/UploadApplet_buttonCheckJTwain_actionAdapter.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/UploadApplet_buttonInstallJVM_actionAdapter.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/UploadApplet_buttonScan_actionAdapter.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/UploadApplet_buttonUpload_actionAdapter.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/UploadApplet_labelURL_mouseAdapter.class
com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/UploadApplet_useProxy_actionAdapter.class
```

And here's the Code for the JTwainApplet

```
    import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.Image;

import com.asprise.util.jtwain.Source;
import com.asprise.util.jtwain.SourceManager;

/*
 * $Id$
 * 
 */

/**
 * @author  JACK    (Jan 19, 2004)
 */
public class JTwainApplet extends Applet {

    /**
     * @throws java.awt.HeadlessException
     */
    public JTwainApplet() throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.applet.Applet#destroy()
     */
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.destroy();
    }

    public void scan() {
            try {
                // SourceManager.setLibraryPath("E:\\Twain\\Asprise\\JT\\Debug\\JT.dll");
                Source source = SourceManager.instance().getDefaultSource();

                if(source == null) {
                    System.err.println("There is no (default) source on the system!");
                    return;
                }

                source.open();

                Image image = source.acquireImage();

                new ImageDisplayer("DemoSimple", image);

                source.close();

            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                SourceManager.closeSourceManager();
            }
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.applet.Applet#init()
     */
    public void init() {
        super.init();

        System.out.println("Init.");

        scan();

        System.out.println("Scan");
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.applet.Applet#start()
     */
    public void start() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.start();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see java.applet.Applet#stop()
     */
    public void stop() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.stop();
    }

}
```

Lastly my jnpl and html source

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="" href="">
    <information>
        <title>Cache Scanning</title>
        <vendor>Altcom</vendor>
    </information>
    <resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <jar href="http://127.0.0.1:18123/media/java/demo.jar" main="true" />
    </resources>
    <applet-desc 
         name="JTwain Applet Demo"
         main-class="JTwainApplet"
         width="500"
         height="200">
     </applet-desc>
     <update check="background"/>
</jnlp> 



   **javascript** - 
 <script src="http://java.com/js/deployJava.js"></script>    
    <script> 
        var attributes = { code: "http://127.0.0.1:18123/media/java/demo.jar",  width:500, height:200} ; 
        var parameters = {jnlp_href: "http://127.0.0.1:18123/media/java/demo.jnlp"} ; 
        deployJava.runApplet(attributes, parameters, '1.6'); 
    </script>
```

Any suggestions would be greatfully recieved. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Obvious question, but did you sign your JAR?

Comment: Yes, you need a signed jar - completely signed, not only the com.asprise classes. Also, the library which JTwain tries to load must be either included in the jar file (it is not, AFAIKS), or already installed on the system/JRE.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue I hadn't signed all the jars. In the end I created (and signed) a jar with just classes I'd written, then served up the other jar's using the jnpl (one of them needed signing too). Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, this is how I got it working. I stopped using the 'create runnable jar' option in eclipse and just used the 'create jar' option. I then referenced the other jars (JTwain etc), using the manifest (rather than having eclipse try to include them in my jar).

MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: JTwain.jar plugin.jar AspriseJavaPDF.jar
```

I added the other jars to my media folder and served them up using the jnpl -

```
<resources>
        <!-- Application Resources -->
        <j2se version="1.6+"
              href="http://java.sun.com/products/autodl/j2se" />
        <jar href="http://127.0.0.1:18123/media/java/CacheScan.jar" main="true" />
        <jar href="http://127.0.0.1:18123/media/java/JTwain.jar"  />
        <jar href="http://127.0.0.1:18123/media/java/AspriseJavaPDF.jar"  />
        <jar href="http://127.0.0.1:18123/media/java/plugin.jar" />
</resources>
```

Lastly I signed all the unsigned jars (both mine and the AspriseJavaPDF.jar). I did this outside of Eclipse. see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/signindex.html

Having unsigned Jars was the problem so thanks to Perception & Paulo Ebermann for the comments above. Hope this is helpful for somebody.